# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "POST_VACANT_LIST"

Tags: oracle, plsql, syntax-error

whats wrong with this trigger

i need to write a trigger for each update of vehicle_id,status1 columns in taxi_vehiclestatus table and exec a stord procedure called post_vacant_list with new values

```
create or replace trigger vacant_list
    after update of vehicle_id,status1
    on taxi_vehiclestatus
    for each row
    begin
    exec post_vacant_list(:new.vehicle_id, :new.status1);
    end;
    /
```

2/6

```
 2/6     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "POST_VACANT_LIST" when expecting one of the following:
      := . ( @ % ;
      The symbol ":=" was substituted for "POST_VACANT_LIST" to continue.
```

Comment: `exec` is a SQL*Plus [command](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve022.htm) that can be used to execute a single PL/SQL statement. It's not a PL/SQL [language construct](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/reservewords.htm) so it can't be used as such.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use exec here. Just use the procedures name without exec:

```
post_vacant_list(:new.vehicle_id, :new.status1);
```